# Calling c++ functions

Tags: c++

this is my first question here on stackoverflow so I hope it all comes out formatted correctly. I'm working on an assignment for my programming course and we have to write a program that takes two inputs and then produces a readout of results. I had to create two functions that ask which concert a person would like to attend and then how many tickets they would like to purchase for that concert. I've created the functions but now I'm having trouble calling the functions in order to print my results.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char GetConcert()
{
   char Concert;
   cout << "The following concerts are available:\n";
   cout << "     B for Beyonce\n";
   cout << "     L for Lady Gaga\n";
   cout << "     T for Taylor Swift\n";
   cout << "Enter the letter for the concert you want:\n";
   cin >> Concert;
   return Concert;
}

int GetNumTickets()
{
   int NumTickets;
   cout << "Enter the number of tickets you want:\n";
   cin >> NumTickets;
   while ((NumTickets < 0) || (NumTickets > 10))
   {
      if (NumTickets < 0)
         cout << "You can not sell tickets here.\n";
      else if (NumTickets > 10)
         cout << "You may not purchase more than 10 tickets.\n";
      cout << "Enter the number oftickets you want:\n";
      cin >> NumTickets;
   }
   return NumTickets;
}

int main()
{
   // Declare Variables
   char Concert;
   int NumTickets;

   // Call function to find out the concert they want to attend


   // Call function to find out how many tickets they want

   // Print out the information you have collected.
   cout << "\nThe customer has placed the following order:\n";
   cout << "Concert: " << Concert << endl;
   cout << "Number of Tickets: " << NumTickets << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I've declared my variables in the main section, but when I try to call the function, it says that I can't switch from integer to character.

Comment: Show the code that triggered the error. Show the exact and complete text of the error message; don't paraphrase.

Comment: main.cpp|40|error: invalid conversion from 'char (*)()' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: What code is in main.cpp on line 40?

Comment: I just need help with the proper code to call the two outputs of my function so that I can print the results.

Comment: `Concert=GetConcert();`

Comment: That was much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a function in c++ you need `()` at the end of the function name. In this example `GetNumTickets()` and `GetConcert()`. Since these functions are also returning values, it is important to save the returned values in order to use them later or to use them right away. You could try:

```
char Concert = GetConcert();
int NumTickets = GetNumTickets();
```